# Spark throws java.io.IOException: Failed to rename when saving part-xxxxx.gz

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, io, rdd

New Spark user here. I'm extracting features from many .tif images stored on AWS S3, each with identifier like 02_R4_C7. I'm using Spark 2.2.1 and hadoop 2.7.2.

I'm using all default configurations like so:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Feature Extraction")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

And here is the function call that this fails on after some features are successfully saved in an image id folder as part-xxxx.gz files:

`features_labels_rdd.saveAsTextFile(text_rdd_direct,"org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")`

See error below. When I delete the feature part-xxxx.gz files that were successfully created and rerun the script, it fails at a different image and part-xxxxx.gz in a seemingly nondeterminsitic way. I make sure to remove all features before rerunning. My theory is that two workers are trying to create the same temp file and are conflicting with each other, since there are two identical error messages for the same file, but one second apart.

I'm at a loss about what to do about this, I've seen that spark lists [configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) that can change how spark handles tasks but I'm not sure what would help here since I don't understand the issue I'm having. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
*SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark/jars/slf4j- 
log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/06/26 19:24:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/06/26 19:24:41 WARN spark.SparkConf: In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
n images = 512
 Feature file of 02_R4_C7 is created                                            
[Stage 3:=================>                                       (6 + 14) / 20]18/06/26 19:24:58 ERROR mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: Error committing the output of task: attempt_20180626192453_0003_m_000007_59
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename FileStatus{path=s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180626192453_0003_m_000007_59/part-00007.gz; isDirectory=false; length=952309; replication=1; blocksize=67108864; modification_time=1530041098000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/part-00007.gz
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitTask(OutputCommitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter.commit(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[Stage 3:=====================================>                   (13 + 7) / 20]18/06/26 19:24:58 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 59)
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename FileStatus{path=s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180626192453_0003_m_000007_59/part-00007.gz; isDirectory=false; length=952309; replication=1; blocksize=67108864; modification_time=1530041098000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/part-00007.gz
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitTask(OutputCommitter.java:343)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter.commit(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1146)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/06/26 19:24:58 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 7 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_feature_extraction_spark.py", line 88, in <module>
    main(sc)
  File "run_feature_extraction_spark.py", line 75, in main
    features_labels_rdd.saveAsTextFile(text_rdd_direct, "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1551, in saveAsTextFile
    keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o76.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 59, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Failed to rename FileStatus{path=s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180626192453_0003_m_000007_59/part-00007.gz; isDirectory=false; length=952309; replication=1; blocksize=67108864; modification_time=1530041098000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C6/part-00007.gz*
```

And when I run it again, the script makes it farther but fails with the same error with a different image folder and part-xxxx.gz file

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/06/26 19:37:24 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/06/26 19:37:24 WARN spark.SparkConf: In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
n images = 512

 Feature file of 02_R4_C7 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C6 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C5 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C4 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C3 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C2 is created                                            
 Feature file of 02_R4_C1 is created                                            
[Stage 15:==========================================>             (15 + 5) / 20]18/06/26 19:38:16 ERROR mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: Error committing the output of task: attempt_20180626193811_0015_m_000017_285
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename FileStatus{path=s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C0/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180626193811_0015_m_000017_285/part-00017.gz; isDirectory=false; length=896020; replication=1; blocksize=67108864; modification_time=1530041897000; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} to s3n://activemapper/imagery/southafrica/wv2/RDD48FeaturesTextFile/02_R4_C0/part-00017.gz
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not safe to use S3 as a direct destination of work without a "consistency layer" (Consistent EMR, or from the Apache Hadoop project itself, S3Guard), or a Special output committer designed explicitly for work with S3 (Hadoop 3.1+ "the S3A committers"). Rename is where things fail, as listing inconsistency means that the scan for files to copy may miss data, or find deleted files which it can't rename. Your stack trace looks exactly how I'd expect this to surface: job commits failing apparently at random.

Rather than go into the details, here's a video of [Ryan Blue on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgHrff5yAQo)

Workaround: write to your local cluster FS then use distcp to upload to S3.

PS: for Hadoop 2.7+, switch to the s3a:// connector. It has exactly the same consistency problem without S3Guard enabled, but better performance.

Comment: I am having similar problems using df.write.partitionBy('col') with s3a://.  I've never had this problem until I used the partitionBy with the write.  Any suggestions on why the partitionBy is causing these rename errors? Thanks!

Comment: tanner, this is related to 404 caching, where a HEAD For a file can cache a 404 in the s3A load balancers for at least 10s; longer if more HEAD calls are made. Its likely  some short files are being created and the gap between create() and close() on the returned stream is so short this surfaces. Fix: use the new committers with Hadoop 3.1+ artifacts

Comment: @Steve Loughran I am not using S3 , but while writing on my EMR hdfs://path I am facing this issue ...how to fix this issue , please suggest?

Comment: @Steve Loughran Can you please suggest how to handle this in hdfs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Comment: don't go near HDFS. that is not a consistency or 404 caching problem. Also: EMR is a closed source fork of hadoop, spark etc. Raise a support issue with them.

Answer (score 9):

The solutions in @Steve Loughran post are great. Just to add a little info to help explaining the issue.

Hadoop-2.7 uses Hadoop Commit Protocol for committing. When Spark saves result to S3, it actually saves temporary result to S3 first and make it visible by renaming it when job succeeds (reason and detail can be found in this great [doc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html)). However, S3 is an object store and does not have real "rename"; it *copy* the data to target object, then *delete* original object.

S3 is "eventually consistent", which means the *delete* operation could happen before *copy* is fully synced. When this happens, the rename would fail.

In my cases, this was only triggered in some chained jobs. I haven't seen this in simple save job.

Comment: I've discovered one more cause of this: cached 404s in the S3 load balancer. If anything looks for a file existing via a HEAD call, a 404 can be cached which can be returned afterwards, even 20-30s. the list sees the file, but the copy fails. We're tuning that in S3a to remove those checks when creating files with overwrite==true, but it'll take a while for that to ship in hadoop-3.2.x. For now: leave a gap between create and rename *without looking for the file*

Comment: I am getting the same rename error when I use  spark.write.partitionBy('col') to s3a://.  Anythoughts on why this is happening?  Any work arounds? Thanks!

Comment: @TannerClark As mentioned in Steven Loughran's earlier post, you could write to local cluster first, then load result to S3 using ```distcp``` or ```aws s3 cp```.

Comment: Not my best work, but I am looping through the partition field and exporting each partition (since I only have 45 large partitions). No failures!

Comment: @Fang Zhang I am not using S3 , but while writing on my EMR hdfs://path I am facing this issue ...how to fix this issue , please suggest?

Comment: @Fang Zhang Can you please suggest how to handle this in hdfs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is no thread available to take up a concurrent task.Setting  the below property in hdfs works

`dfs.datanode.handler.count = >10`

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting below errors but all issues got resolved after switching from s3a to s3 as s3 is offering strong consistency now

"Aborting task
java.io.IOException: Failed to rename S3AFileStatus{path=s3a://...
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:478)"

and
"WARN FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete s3a://...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to rename S3AFileStatus{path=s3a://"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very useful answer, since evidently things have changed since the original question was posted and answered. However, it would be even more useful if it included a link to documentation on the change in S3 (that it now offers strong consistency), and it doesn't need to include the error snippets, since they don't add any details about what the fix actually is :)